# Restart python with subprocesses and threads

Tags: python, restart

How should look restart a python program with sub processes and multithreads inside those sub processes and with writing to the files.
Program are using external API.

What about should I remember? I thin that is a huge problem. From more expired programmers I need a path how to do it.

1. How to wait for end of writing to files?
2. How to finish threads?
3. How to finish sub processes?
4. How to disconnect API?

Probably the most important will be fail coming from API.

EDITED

I will describe structure of my program.

I have main.py script for preparing a files. From main.py script i am caling main_suproceses.py. In main_subprocesees i have loop which inside is calling next sub processes.
Each suprocess are working on files and have multithreading and have API connection.

I will need reebot my process if I will got exception from API or from reading a file.

Regards

Comment: Do you have the ability to shut down the program right now?

Comment: No. Right now I have program with few gnome terminal. Each subprocess have own gnome terminal. That was easiest way for printing messages and debuging.  if subprocess will finished  terminal and process is closed. If not I have to close all windows and sometimes kill porcesses.  Now I know that I had to build restartability. For example if i will have timeout from API.

Comment: If you have not designed the system with shutdown in mind, then what you're asking is very difficult.  You need a way to signal the subprocesses to shut down.

Comment: Ok. First I will looking for info about signal. First I have to learn and understand how signals are working.